# The session is idle and there is no current transaction pgAdmin - Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, pgadmin

I'm really new in Postgres and PgAdmin.
I'm trying to import new attributes in to my database class from Django project. This project is connected to pgAdmin Postgres. The problem is when I make migrations and migrate from django, this news attributes doesn't impact my database in pgAdmin.
I see my migrations files in django project and the migration is successful, but when I see pgadmin it shows this message `The session is idle and there is no current transaction pgAdmin`

I have searched in google but there is no so much information, so I really will appreciate your help.

[image]

Comment: That's not an error message, it would be there regardless of whether or not the migrations worked. Why do you think they didn't?

Comment: There is no pgAdmin Postgres. There is the server software Postgres and there is the client software pgAdmin.  It is important to remember they are independent programs, which may impact what you are seeing. In other words are you sure that the database you did the migration against is the same one you are looking at with pgAdmin?